# Opening the oldest file in a folder

Tags: applescript

I've been looking for how to open the oldest file in a folder. I've made a weather station that logs the data onto an SD card with a new file each day. The month and year are the file name with "WX" added to it. Every file is on the SD card, so the location is always the same (WX Data in Finder). All the files are CSV files. Once the file is open, I have AppleScript analyze the data. That part works when I open the file and select the first cell (A1). I want to be able to plug in the SD card, start the script and have it open the oldest file, analyze it, paste the results on another Numbers spreadsheet, delete the file from the SD card and open the next one to repeat till all the files are analyzed. All the code examples I've found either don't work or need to make the process way more complicated than I need.

This is what I have so far. It opens Numbers, but with an error saying the file can't be found:

```
set result to "WXDATA"
set sourceFolder to result

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    sort (sourceFolder) by creation date
    --sort (get files of sourceFolder) by creation date
    -- This raises an error if the folder doesn't contain any files
    set theFile to (item 1 of result) as alias
end tell
```

The result is:

> alias "WXDATA:"

I have some lines commented out while I try different things.

How can I get this to open the oldest, and first file, listed on the SD card? Numbers opens, but it doesn't look like it knows what file to open.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the files of the source folder and add a `try` block to handle the error if the folder is empty

```
set diskName to "WXDATA"

tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to disk diskName
    try
        set theFile to item 1 of (sort files of sourceFolder by creation date) as alias
    on error
        set theFile to missing value
    end try
end tell
if theFile is not missing value then
    tell application "Numbers" to open theFile
end if
```